# Will Room migrations be run for new users?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Let's say I have 2 migrations (1-->2, 2-->3). If a new user comes along and installs the app, will all the migrations be run, or will they just get the version 3 schema database?

Comment: See this link https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929

Comment: Thanks @MahabubKarim, I've read that a couple of times but I'm still not confident in what the answer to my question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll just get version 3. Databases internally track their database version and that is what Room uses to check if a migration is needed. In the case of a brand new database, Room just starts the user at the version of the database you specify.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, I was afraid of that. I'm used to Rails backends where all migrations are always run. This means one should never add an `INSERT INTO...` after a `CREATE TABLE...` in a migration.

Comment: Right, the only reason you'd be inserting data as part of your migration is if you're inserting data you've read from a previous version of the table. Migrations are not how you pre-populate a database - you'd want to follow [the existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62185732) for that kind of support.